# Timeout Notification Telerik problem with browser multi tab

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik

When a user open the site in two tabs (same browser). Then, the user is working in 1st opened tab for 5 min (time setted for timeout), the session will expire because 2nd tab remained without action (a telerik:RadNotification will appear).

Same Session ID is shared among both tabs. Using SessionState mode = "InProc".

How to avoid this behaviour and be able to open multiple tabs?

Comment: What controls are you using ?  How the timout is set on those controls ?  Did you try invoking timeout from javascript instead of  Session ?

Comment: using exactly same as on telerick demo web site: https://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/notification/examples/sessiontimeout/defaultcs.aspx

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have set session time out to be 5 minutes. 
Irrespective of what you try, session timeout will happen after 5 min.

One way you can try is to make it sliding expiration.  That way your session timeout would be moved by 5 minutes after every interaction with the page.

But even in that case, if you open multiple tabs and dont do anything in any of the tab, your session will expire as Session timeout is based on cookies and generally in all modern browsers cookies are shared across tabs.

Session expires if postback does not happen in session timeout duration. 
You will have to make sure some kind of information is sent to server to keep session alive.

One solution is meta refresh  as explained [in this blog.](http://www.primaryobjects.com/2008/01/29/preventing-session-timeouts-in-c-asp-net-web-applications/):

In Master file include:

```
<IFRAME ID="KeepAliveFrame" src="KeepSessionAlive.aspx" frameBorder="0" width="0" height="0" runat="server"></IFRAME>
```

**KeepSessionAlive.aspx:**

```
<meta id="MetaRefresh" http-equiv="refresh" content="21600;url=KeepSessionAlive.aspx" runat="server" />
<script language="javascript">
   window.status = "<%=WindowStatusText%>";
</script>
```

**KeepSessionAlive.aspx.cs**

```
protected string WindowStatusText = "";

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
   {
      // Refresh this page 60 seconds before session timeout, effectively resetting the session timeout counter.
      MetaRefresh.Attributes["content"] = Convert.ToString((Session.Timeout * 60) - 60) + ";url=KeepSessionAlive.aspx?q=" + DateTime.Now.Ticks;
      WindowStatusText = "Last refresh " + DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString() + " " + DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString();
   }
}
```

Comment: This is my problem -> when I open multiple tabs and do nothing in them (only working in one tab). I got kick out after 5 min because session was expired in other tab. Using Chrome.

Comment: But you have not set sliding expiration, that's why it is happening.  You will have to set the sliding expiration then it should work as you want.

Comment: Sorry, did not mentionned in the comments. I setted slidingExpiration="true". Tested, still the same problem.

Comment: Is your authentication timeout and session timeout not the same ?

Comment: Updated my answer.   i would suggest to read about authentication cookie time out vs session timeout for better understanding of session timeout and why refresh is required.

Comment: They are the same